# componentDidMount not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Header component that suppose to render his child components by a the condition of if the user is logged. It recognize the condition by the session-storage. I tried to control the rendering by 
`componentDidMount`:

```
renderUserHeader = () => {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')) {
    var tokenToSend = { token: sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth') }
    var regJSONED = JSON.stringify(tokenToSend)

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: regJSONED
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('HTTP error ' + response.status)
      }
      return response.text()
    })
    .then(data => {
      let JsonedUserName = JSON.parse(data)

      this.setStateUserName(JsonedUserName.name, JsonedUserName.admin)
    })

    if (!this.state.admin) {
      return <UserHeader name={this.state.userName} />
    } else if (this.state.admin) {
      return <AdminHeader name={this.state.userName} />
    }

  } else if (!sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')) {
    return (
      <Link to='/login'>
        {' '}
        <LoginLink />{' '}
      </Link>
    )
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.renderUserHeader()
}
```

As you can see the `renderUserHeader` is being the component did mount but it is not working.

I have tried calling `renderUserHeader` inside the render and it worked but it keeps bugging and I have to refresh the page everytime.

```
render() {
  return (
    <header>
      <Logo />
      {this.renderUserHeader()}
    </header>
  )
}
```

Can someone tell me why `componentDidMount` doesn't not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use conditional rendering with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
{this.state.isLoggedIn ? (some JSX if true) : (some JSX if false or just NULL)}
```

in the componentDidMount you can set the isLoggedIn property in the state, so every time the component loads - (render method will run) - the condition will be checked again

Answer (score 7):

componentDidMount is used for side effects like fetching data and updating component state only. If you return some component (eg `<Link />`) from componentDidMount it won't be rendered. 
And you should never do any side effects inside render.

Instead, you should fetch and update state in the componentDidMount and based on the state render corresponding components.

Answer (score 1):

**componentDidMount not rendering**

as said in above answer:componentDidMount is used for side effects like fetching data and updating component state only.
now

**how to make it work with your code**

in order to make it work,your componentDidMount should be like

```
componentDidMount(){

 if(sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')){
   var tokenToSend = {token: sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')}
   var regJSONED = JSON.stringify(tokenToSend)

fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body:  regJSONED,

}).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text(); 
})
.then(data => {
  let JsonedUserName = JSON.parse(data)

  this.setStateUserName(JsonedUserName.name,JsonedUserName.admin )

  })
}
```

and your renderUserHeader should be like

```
renderUserHeader = () =>{
   if(!sessionStorage.getItem('user-auth')){
      return   <Link to="/login"> <LoginLink /> </Link>
   }
  if(!this.state.admin){
    return <UserHeader name ={this.state.userName}/>
  }
  else if(this.state.admin){
    return  <AdminHeader name ={this.state.userName}/> 
  }

 }
```

and you can call it from render method.